# how to customize time_select helper ? Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using time_select helper on a site that has Right-To-Left Text ().

Therefore the time_select turns over in the html output (The hour select is before the minute select).

How can I make the minute select be before the hour select?

Thanks,

Oded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unlike the date_select, time_select doesn't have an order option unfortunately.

What you could do:

1. use [select_hour](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/select_hour) and [select_minute](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/select_minute) to customize it
2. use `time_select` and do a CSS trick and apply `float: left;` (or maybe `float: right;`) to the minute select field, you can identify the minute select by the id which looks like `objectname_fieldname_5i` so if you call `time_select('myobject', 'myfield')` the id is `myobject_myfield_5i`